# Delete a row javascript using row id

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

Hi guys I have a table created by php in this way:

```
  foreach ($query as $row): ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo  $row->aic;?>" > 

                    <td><?php echo $row->aic; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->denominazione ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->quantita; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->alert; ?></td>
                    <td>
                         <a id="bt_modifica"
                                class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                 data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                 data-placement="top" 
                                 title="" 
                                 data-original-title="Modifica">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/images/Modifica.png">
                        </a> 
                           <a id="bt_elimina>"
                                  class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                                  data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                 data-placement="top" 
                                 title=""
                                 data-original-title="Elimina"
                                 onclick="deleteRow(<?php echo $row->aic ?>))">

                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/images/Elimina.png"> 
                        </a> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php 

            endforeach; ?>


            </tbody>
```

I need to delete row by rowId. This table has the dynamics id.
The columns ids are the same id of the sql table; in effect aic is id of sql table! In this way I are sure that the HTML row id is unique.
This is script

```
function deleteRow(rowID)
{   var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
    row.parentElement.removeChild(row);
        alert(rowID);

            }
}
```

this code don't delete row.

Comment: And what is your problem ? or question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
onclick="deleteRow(deleteRow(<?php echo $row->aic ?>))">
```

to

```
onclick="deleteRow(<?php echo $row->aic ?>)">
```

Another potential issue is that this:

```
<?php echo $row->aic ?>
```

may not be a number. So, you need to quote it. That is, change:

```
onclick="deleteRow(<?php echo $row->aic ?>)">
```

to:

```
onclick="deleteRow(\"<?php echo $row->aic ?>\")">
```

Comment: don't work. This is an copy error. In my code I have onclick="deleteRow(<?php echo $row->aic ?>)">

Comment: I tried in my machine. It works fine. Did you see any error in the browser's console? Can you give example of HTML page returned by this php script? I want to see how the ID looks like.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another potential issue. Please check.

Comment: does not perform any action. Not even show the alert.

Comment: Copy paste the HTML produced by your php script. It will helps us to debug.

Comment: Ensure that you add the quotes correctly. See my answer again.

Comment: another question: is possible in deleteRow function make ajax call?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It is better to open another question, if you have specific problem to discuss.

Comment: Yes, thanks. You can see that the answer is checked.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues -

- The one that might be causing issue - Incorrect Function Name
- Other one - Calling deleteRow() twice - within each other (this should not cause any issue though)

So, just change -

```
function eliminaProdotto(rowID)
```

to -

```
function deleteRow(rowID)
```

Edit:

Based on modified question -

Is $row->aic a string? If yes, then add quotes around it...

```
onclick="deleteRow('<?php echo $row->aic ?>')"
```

Comment: Looks like too many typos in the original question... @user2464063 - check the edited answer.